# dotnet is not installing tools and packages even though it claims it has

Tags: c#, .net-core, neovim

attempting to follow the install instructions in the csharp-ls readme, copy pasting the command exactly,

`dotnet tool install --global csharp-ls`

dotnet tells me that csharp-ls was installed successfully, but the command does not execute it. Returns `command not found`. The tool is not in  `$HOME/.dontet/tools`. Trying to install again returns 'csharp-ls is already installed'.

- Environment: WSL2 Ubuntu on windows10
- Dotnet version 7.0.403

Things I have tried

- restarting wsl, and windows
- uninstalling and reinstalling dotnet7 form the Microsoft PPA
- verified .dotnet/tools is in my path

I do not know where or if the package is actually downloaded to my machine. I can not find it anywhere.

What could be causing this problem and how might I solve it?

---

UPDATES:

There appears to be a pathing issue with my instance of dotnet, I just discovered that running `dotnet restore` in my project also claims to have completed successfully but none of the packages that were supposedly installed are in the .nuget directory. I do not know where they are if they actually were installed.

Similarly to the dotnet tool issue, attempting to restore again returns `packages already up to date`

I tried:

- Manually settings environment variable `NUGET_PACKAGES` to the `$HOME/.nuget/packages` directory

---

running dotnet restore with flag `--verbosity=diagnostic` shows the DOTNET_HOST_PATH as `/user/share/dotnet/dotnet`

executing `which dotnet` returns `/usr/bin/dotnet`

it is my understanding that these should be the same... is that correct?

---

I have been running restore with sudo, I thought perhaps this was causing the discrepency in the executables path. However running without sudo still shows DOTNET_HOST_PATH as `usr/share/dotnet` and `which dotnet` still returns `usr/bin/dotnet`.

I tried to manually set the DOTNET_HOST_PATH environment variable, I did source the rc file and confirmed with echo.

dotnet restore is still using `usr/shar/dotnet`

Comment: so what's your problem now, can you summarize? Initially  you didn't see a dotnet binary, now it's accessible? How it's related to `dotnet restore`?

Comment: In my experience running `dotnet` as sudo brings a bunch of issues (which I never really tried to understand), so I'm not surprised that `sudo dotnet restore` is behaving oddly, but I don't think it's necessarily why your global tool install is borked.

Comment: You could confirm that the problem really is "the tool got installed into a funny place" by testing that you can install the tool _locally_, and still run it. That still worked for me even when [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75045975/2821583) was unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are using windows version instead of linux version by mistake. Try `which dotnet` and verify the command's path.

If not, my best bet is you are missing file permissions and you can easily fix this by `chmod +x` on the `csharp-ls` file to make it executable

As a workaround, since you do not find the `csharp-ls` file in /.dotnet/tools, you can download it straight from the source repository or package feed, then placing it in the directory that's listed in your PATH.

Comment: which dotnet return /usr/bin/dotnet, Part of my problem is that i can not find csharp-ls file.It should be in .dotnet/tools but is not'

Comment: Can you check what ``dotnet tool list --global --tool-path`` gives as path?

Comment: A quick workaround for you is to simply download the ```csharp-ls``` tool from the source repo and placing it in the directory. That will work but is only an alternative. My main concern is your tool-path might be incorrect hence why stuff are getting installed, but not in /.dotnet/tools

Comment: `dotnet tool list --global --tool-path` is not a valid command, it expects a path as an argument and lists the tools in that path. It doesnt return a path for the tool location for you. BTW I am updating the original question with more information. It does appear to be a pathing issue but i can not find the root cause of it or where things are actually being installed at.

Comment: however when I run `dotnet tool list --global` i get the single tool that exists in my .dotnet/tools folder which is the git credential manager. So that command appears to be looking in the correct place

Comment: `--global` and `--tool-path` can't be used together. I'd suggest (1) install the tool to a specific directory, like `dotnet tool install csharp-ls --tool-path ~/wtf`, then (2) checking that you can run it (`~/wtf/csharp-ls`) and (3) you can list it (`dotnet tool list --tool-path ~/wtf`)